# problem with playing a Sound object with the desired point

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to make a player with EQ, get the data in the Sound object, but for some reason with the desired point to play it I can not play it right from the start of the track.

```
    _out_snd.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound);
    _channel = _out_snd.play(pos);

function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void {

    _samples = new ByteArray();
    var len:Number = buf[trackDesc].sound.extract(_samples, BUFFER_SIZE);
    var i:int=0;
    var l:Number;
    var r:Number;

    if ( len < BUFFER_SIZE ) { // If end of MP3, start over
        len += buf[trackDesc].sound.extract(_samples,BUFFER_SIZE-len,0);
    }
    _samples.position = 0;
    while (i < BUFFER_SIZE) {
        event.data.writeFloat(_eqL.compute(_samples.readFloat()));
        event.data.writeFloat(_eqR.compute(_samples.readFloat()));
        i++;
    }
}
```

please help, thanks in advance:)

Comment: have you looked into computeSpectrum?

Comment: in my opinion it is absolutely nothing to do with, computeSpectrum creates snapshot of the current sound wave and places it into the specified ByteArray object/

Comment: Ah I mistook what you are trying to do.

Comment: What size is BUFFER_SIZE

Comment: I would verify _samples.readFloat() has a value in the loop where you writeFloat

Answer (score 0):

After I have all earned the position of the track

```
var len:Number = buf[trackDesc].sound.extract(_samples, BUFFER_SIZE,event.position);
```